# Is it possible to achieve 50,000 active connections between iPhones and a server using websockets?

Tags: ios, iphone, websocket

**Architecture**

- Assume you can download an iPhone app that does something useful but one of the requirements is to become part of the collective computation procedure as a node.
- Each iPhone app is connected to a server and receives queries (<100 bytes) regularly (one per minute) only when the user is actively using the app of course. (no background tasks)
- Each iPhone app processes the queries (very low impact on performance and battery life) and sends responses (<1KB) rarely (only when the process has yielded something significant).

**Data Type**

- Small sized plain text

**Functionality**

- When an iPhone app asks for a query to be resolved instead of making the server responsible for processing it, the server sends the query to all iPhones currently online. Each iPhone that has a solution sends it to the server and the server sends it back to the iPhone that asked the question. The server becomes a messenger and can dedicate its resources for solving different kinds of problems relevant to the procedure that inherently can't be solved on each iPhone individual. For example, an autocomplete function for queries and answers since the server will know all the queries ever asked but a single iPhone app couldn't because it would be offline most of the time.

**Barriers**

- Networking: How do you connect all 50,000 iPhones to a server with websockets? How do you send the query to the server, from the server to all 50,000 iPhones separately and back to the iPhone that asked the question?

*I know there are a lot of issues to be addressed but the scale of the core functionality is the biggest one so far.*

**Example**

1. An iPhone with an ID of "73869485" asks "is curiosity on mars still functioning?" --> Server
2. Server "is curiosity on mars still functioning?" --> 49,999 currently online iPhones
3. Processing occurs in each iPhone individually.
4. 6 iPhones send interesting answers "array of 6 answers" -->  Server
5. Server "array of 6 answers" --> iPhone with an ID of "73869485"

Comment: You need either client-side P2P or server-side load balancers interconnected (via something like AMQP) to form a distributed network, which is basically P2P

Comment: Unless the primary purpose of your app is to allow people to answer questions, your app probably doesn't meet requirement 2.4.2 of the App Store review guidelines